# Rendering certain number of child components in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following issue. I have a parent component that will render certain number of child components based on some calculation. So I have the following:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
      <child-element [count]="count"></child-element>
   `
   directives: [ChildElement]
})
```

and then in Child element I want to do something like

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child-element',
   template: `
      <ul>
         <another-element *ngFor="//here should be the count number of elements//"></another-element>
      </ul>
   `
})
```

What comes to my mind is to create a for loop and create `count` number of elements and then loop through that array in the template, but is there any better approach? Also ideally I should be able to pass some additional properties to `another-element`

thanks

Comment: Instead of passing `count`, have you tried passing in an array of objects?  Then you could run your `ngFor` loop over that array, and pull out the additional properties from the object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you.

Input: `@Input () count: number;`

Helper: `range(count)`

created: `<child-element [count]="5"></child-element>`

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-element',
    template: `<li *ngFor="#int of range(count)"> Hello </li>`    
})

export class ChildElement{

    @Input () count: number;

    constructor(){

    }

    range = (value) => { 
        let a = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < value; ++i) { 
            a.push(i+1) 
        } 
     return a; 
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
              <h1>Hello World Angular2</h1> 
              <child-element [count]="5"></child-element>
              `,
    directives: [ChildElement]
})

export class App {
    constructor(){

    }
}
```

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/esnFDdexaDvV8czAgszB?p=preview)</kbd>